# SQL Sequence per column

Tags: sql-server, count, sequence

**Table**

```
City    Classes
------------------
SCL        X
SCL        Y
SCL        Z
Blah       X
Blah       Y
Narf       X
```

Query to get this output:

```
City Classes Sequence
SCL     X       1
SCL     Y       2
SCL     Z       3
Blah    X       1
Blah    Y       2
Narf    X       1
```

Can someone help me and show me how to achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ... ??

Comment: I want to generate the sequence in the table result, but it should be per value. In my example sequence is generated per City.  Please refer to my table and output I am trying to achieve. Please help me how to write a query to generate this

Comment: Then why `Narf` starts with `3`

Comment: Sorry it should start with 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  City, 
  Classes, 
  row_number() over (partition by City order by classes) Sequence
FROM (values
('SCL','X'),('SCL','Y'),('SCL','Z'),
('Blah','X'),('Blah','Y'),('Narf','X')) x(City, Classes)
```

Result:

```
City   Classes  Sequence
Blah   X        1
Blah   Y        2
Narf   X        1
SCL    X        1
SCL    Y        2
SCL    Z        3
```

Comment: Thank you. with your answer I am able to solve my problem very soon.